# how to remove an iframe by its source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Sorry if I didn't get the title right, I don't usually use  javascript, anyway my site has this really really annoying iframe that loads in and I have tried very hard to remove it ( iframe.websitebuilder.com/editor/freeSiteUnder/49170742)

so far what I have tried is the following:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('page-editor');
    }
```

**what this was supposed to do is remove the class which the iframe was loaded under in hopes it would fix my issue**, instead it did not fix that and never even removed the page editor class.

I'm hoping someone can provide a solution, or point me in the right direction of a solution.

Comment: What is `elements`?  Show the code that creates that var.

Comment: elements was all of the elements on the page put into a list

Comment: I'm trying to find a different way to remove the iframe thats why I asked

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the little code you've posted.  You need to add more code and context to this question to get any helpful advice

Comment: let me rephrase my question, the code did work, it just did not fix my problem.

Comment: _"it did not fix that and never even removed the page editor class."_ sure sounds like this code didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When is that routine going to run? Did you put it in onload event handler or are you just running it in the html directly? Because there is a possibility that your routine is being called before the iframe is created.

Use something like this for test

```
setTimeout( function() { 
    ... your Routine ... 
}, 5000 );
```

and see if it works. But you should wait 5 seconds to see the results.

And a better solution (if possible) is to run that routine in the onload event handler. So in your html element definition you put something like

```
   <html onload="init();">
```

and then in your javascript code you do something like

```
function init() {
    ... your routine ...
}
```